# How can I save files to ADLS from Azure Databricks python notebook?

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

Does anyone know how can I save screenshots from a databricks notebook directly to ADLS.
I have set up the connection but for some reason I cannot do it directly so I have so save to DBFS then move the files to ADLS
Currently this works:

```
driver.save_screenshot('/dbfs/test.png')
dbutils.fs.mv('dbfs:/', 'abfss://<container>@<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net/', recurse=True)
```

Ideally, I want to do this in a single step rather than saving in the root storage than moving so something like this:

```
driver.save_screenshot('abfss://<container>@<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net/test.png')
or
driver.save_screenshot('/abfss/<storage-account>/<container>/test.png')
```

Finally, does setting up the Unity Catalog and a corresponding Metastore help in changing the DBFS root storage location to ADLS so I can directly use the container without specifying the links everytime? What are the best practices in such cases?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Databricks considers **'abfss'** as an external path so some functions only consider local path to save files

[image]

Instead of using **'abfss'** path  we have to provide **'mnt path'** to save file directly into **ADLS**.

[image]

```
driver.save_screenshot('/mnt/Input_path/<foldername>/test.png')
```